# Calling make from Python on Windows results in Makefile error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to call `make build` from Python script on Windows. 
Since `make` is not available by default on Windows, I've installed GnuWin32 edition. To limit variances the only command under build is `pwd`

Running in cmd is OK and would print current dir. Running from Python as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['make', 'build'])
```

would result in the error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, pwd, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: could you try adding `shell=True` as an argument to `subprocess.run()` and see if that works?

Comment: no difference - same error

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64` to the path